# Grafana calculate sum in selected timeframe only

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am running the following query in Grafana in order to calculate the percentage of notifications that had a latency of over 3600 seconds. My data is coming from prometheus using a histogram vector.

```
(sum (notification_latency_bucket{le=“+Inf”}) by (notification_type) 
- sum (notification_latency_bucket{le=“3600"}) by (notification_type)) 
/ sum (notification_latency_bucket{le=“+Inf”}) by (notification_type)
```

My issue is that this sum is being calculated since the latest restart of my service and completely ignores the provided timeframe. Would it be possible to modify this query to only show changes in the given timeframe? I have tried adding

`(sum (notification_latency_bucket{le=“+Inf”}[$__interval]) by (notification_type)`

to the queries, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine sum and rate as described in the [Prom-QL documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/). I also encourage you to prefer $__rate_interval over $__intervall. Sometimes it is even better to use longer intervals such as 5m (depending on the data changes and the scrape interval).